# Attributes for points created by Intersect tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, gps, intersect

**Scenario:**
I am using ArcMap 10.3.1 to find the locations where an animal crosses a road from GPS data and the associated attributes such as X and Y (which I can calculate) and the date and time of each road crossing event. The date and time information of the GPS data is in a shapefile.

**So far:**
I have created the road crossing locations using the intersect tool for the GPS data shapefile and a road network shpapefile. I have calculated the XY of each road crossing location.

**The problem:**
I would like to get the closest date and time stamp for each crossing location created using the intersect tool, i.e. the date and time of the closest GPS point in the sequence. These timestamps are in the GPS data attribute table.

Is there a way to transfer/get/copy attribute information from the closest point of one point to another in a different shapefile - or combine the shapefiles - or another way entirely?

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation within your posts.

Comment: Explore the spatial join tool, that will pass attribution from one layer to another.

Comment: Shapefile doesn't support a datetime data type. Wouldn't a data format that does, like file geodatabase, make this process easier?